# Public/Private Access from Home Machine without VPN

Tags: azure

I'm working from home, have a personal acct at MS Azure. My internet connection is Google Fiber 1Gb just like many other people. I'm an IT pro but totally green on Azure. While setting up some Azure services, Network connectivity section, `Public access`, `Firewall rules` says Inbound connections from the IP addresses specified below will be allowed, `+ Add current client IP address (123.123.123.1)`. Since I'm using a home router believe this IP address is not static. If `Private access` is chosen, then to use my own `Vnet`. Anyway, how do I set up for personal connection from home?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend setting up OpenVPN on an Azure VM thats in the same VNET as  the instance you want. Also you can make that OpenVPN VM have a static IP and use it for other purposes, the size of the VM can be really small and get it for cheap. The machine for OpenVPN can be found in the marketplace in Azure. There are a lot of YouTube videos for this and you have 2 free clients and you get a pretty nice UI. I would invest in that and you can have that.. VPN for a very long time, if you are ok to pay for a small VM, which you can set to turn off at night and spend even less.

Comment: @KristianKanchev that's worth suggesting as an Answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend trying to use vnet integration from home; [azure vnets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) are complex and can involve [expensive connectivity services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) to connect to them from your home PC.

Instead, I'd recommend defining a suitable ip address range to cover all the addresses your ISP might assign to your router. You will have to do some detective work to find out precisely what ip addresses are controlled by your ISP, but you should end up with a range which you can express in CIDR format, for example 123.123.0.0/16.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Vince's mention, I will add the comment as an optional answer. The answer that Vince gave is valid as both of the things we gave depend on the need, time spending, and pricing.

Answer:
I would recommend setting up OpenVPN on an Azure VM that's in the same VNET as the instance you want. Also, you can make that OpenVPN VM have a static IP and use it for other purposes, the size of the VM can be really small, and get it for cheap. The machine for OpenVPN can be found in the marketplace in Azure. There are a lot of YouTube videos for this and you have 2 free clients and you get a pretty nice UI. I would invest in that and you can have that.. VPN for a very long time, if you are ok to pay for a small VM, which you can set to turn off at night and spend even less.

I used this solution for work cases where we needed specific access without spending a huge amount of money. If you don't want a UI and are fine to work with cli, you can have much more users connected.